# Django pg_restore on local machine

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, pg-restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django: permission denied when trying to access database after restore (migration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233046/django-permission-denied-when-trying-to-access-database-after-restore-migratio)

Having a similar problem to: [After a PostgreSQL restore, I get "permission denied for relation django_session"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302593/after-a-postgresql-restore-i-get-permission-denied-for-relation-django-session) except that the accepted solution is ineffectual, as per heroku docs I created a backup, and curl'd it to my machine, then ran:

```
pg_restore -v -c -Ox -d mydb mydump.dump
```

Initially I got:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: no schema has been selected to create in
```

Then after applying the following in psql...

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO PUBLIC;
GRANT CREATE ON SCHEMA public TO PUBLIC;
```

...I got the same as the SO question above...

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
>>> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: permission denied for relation django_content_type
```

This really threw me, as I have tried --no-acl && --no-owner (-Ox) have made sure to:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE mydb to myuser
```

Using django 1.4, & installed apps include django-CMS... Also, the local copy has been working fine with same user w/ different postgresql DB.

**Oops:**

Apologies for making the classic mistake & assuming my question was **SO** unique; solution was elsewhere  [Django: permission denied when trying to access database after restore (migration)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233046/django-permission-denied-when-trying-to-access-database-after-restore-migratio)

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to user;
GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public to user;
GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public to user;
```

Did the trick; thanks to unwitting savior: @user698585 ;P

Comment: Did you try heroku logs --ps postgres and see if it says anything specific? Can you do heroku pg:sql from inside your app and check access privileges?

Comment: IMHO it would be worth keeping/ merging this Q- with those cited; as neither is complete without the other.